# How to do time comparisons with mysql when timezones are involved?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a table called 'Sessions' with a starts_at field (datetime). I want to apply a filter called 'starts_after' that returns all Sessions that start after a certain time of day (ignoring the date, and only looking at a sessions time). All times are stored in the db as UTC. Easy right? But then comes timezones. Each session belongs to an Event, which has a timezone associated with it.  Right now I have:

```
  time = Time.new('1','1','1','14','00,'00','-07:00)
  Schedulables.where("DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(schedulables.starts_at,'-07:00'), '%H,%i') >
                      DATE_FORMAT('#{time}', '%H,%i')")
```

However, I only get Sessions returned to me who's start time is 17:00 or greater. Its also worth noting that out server time is in EST and the difference between 17:00 and 14:00 is equal to the difference between my server's timezone (-4:00) and the timezone I'm dealing with here (-7:00).

Comment: basically, which ever value DOESN'T change, you convert to the TZ of the other value(s). e.g. if you're doing something like `select * from foo where dbfield=$value`, you'd convert `$value` to the TZ of the dbfield - one conversion at query startup, done. v.s. converting EVERY dbfield to the tz of $value.

Answer (score 0):

`CONVERT_TZ()` requires three arguments.  I only see two so it's not clear how this query works at all.

Your server time zone should be irrelevant.   But I'm guessing that your environment, aware of the time zone of the time value and the server's time zone may be implicitly converting that to server time, in typical "helpful" (read: usually unhelpful) ORM style.

The query you want, in SQL, is more simple than what you are building, and looks like this:

```
WHERE TIME(CONVERT_TZ(schedulables.starts_at,'UTC','-07:00')) >= TIME('14:00:00')
```

...assuming you want things starting at or after 14:00:00 "local" time.  14:00:00 is just a string that the `TIME()` function casts to a time literal.

Better to cast both values as times than to do a lexical comparison with the output of `DATE_FORMAT()`, even though the latter is likely to still be correct.

It may also be that if your environment is "fixing" the time value then you could "unfix" it by declaring it in server time, e.g. `Time.new('1','1','1','14','00,'00','-04:00)`, allowing two incorrect operations to offset each other... or by using `CONVERT_TZ()` to convert to server time instead of local time (since your time value is probably also being converted to server time, silently) but both of these are terrible plans since double-conversions of datetimes are not lossless.

Note that your approach isn't going to scale if there aren't other factors limiting the number of rows to be evaluated.  As a rule, using a column value as an argument to a function in the `WHERE` clause is likely to perform poorly, since it is impossible to resolve such an expression using an index on that column and a full table scan may be required.

Comment: Oops, that was just a bad copy/paste job, I have '00:00' as the second argument in convert_tz. I'll give your suggestions a try, thanks.